# Поменять блоки div местами на JS

Tags: javascript

Как поменять 2 блока `div` местам, где бы они не находились на странице.

Желательно по их `id` и если экран например меньше 1000px

На чистом JS

Comment: можете пожалуйста описать подробнеё? они размещены по position:absolute к странице или их надо поменять их родителей? перекинуть с одного родителя в другой

Comment: @Horchynskyi нет у них вообще свойств. Нужно просто блоки `div` со всем содержимом поменять местами , где бы они не находились

Comment: ну просто если они по position:absolute то нужно менять координатами, если находятся в родителях то уже менять по родителям

Comment: А чем вам jquery не угодил? удобно же.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш ответ в [**этой**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062916/replace-div-with-another-div) теме. 
Если не понятно, вам нужен метод: `.replaceWith()` 
Шпаргалка по нему есть [**тут**](https://ruseller.com/jquery.php?id=42)

Comment: А если внимательно прочитать вопрос? _"На чистом JS"_

Comment: @Qwertiy а вы случаем не в курсе как это можно сделать ?

Comment: @Vipz, в курсе, но возни много... Всё-таки попробуй css...

Comment: @Qwertiy c CSS там совсем не вариант( может подскажите какие функции поковырять ?

Comment: @Vipz Решение не самое идеальное, но может быть и будет его достаточно, заменить innerHtml одного дива на innerHtml другого, через какую-нибудь переменную, возможно этого хватит

Comment: @Vipz Уважаемые пользователи. Если вы получили ответ на свой вопрос, просьба не забывать помечать его как ответ! Это важно!

Comment: @socode Если бы был ответ, я бы с удовольствием это сделал !!!